# Using jOOQs MockResult class in an UPDATE statement for jUnit tests

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am working to set up some unit test cases of my DAO layer to make sure that it is responding in the way that I need it to, and to do so I need to unit test my jOOQ code.  I am running jOOQ 3.6.1 at this time, and trying to use the JDBC mocking as described in this link from the [jOOQ documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/).

My unit testing environment is leveraging jUnit 4.12 and mockito.

Unfortunately, while this works perfectly for SELECT queries, I am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong for UPDATE queries.  In non-jUnit unit testing, I know the function itself is working (it is also pretty basic so that is not shocking), but I would like to be able to have some automated unit tests on this piece of code, too.

My Unit Test is set up in the following manner:

```
public class UserDAOTest {
    private static UserDAO userDAO;
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserDAOTest.class.getName());

    private class MyMockDataProvider implements MockDataProvider {

    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute ( MockExecuteContext ctx ) throws SQLException {
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        MockResult[] result = new MockResult[1];

        String sql = ctx.sql();

        if ( sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("UPDATE") ) {
            Result<UserRecord> userRecordResult = create.newResult(USER);
            userRecordResult.add(create.newRecord(USER));
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.ID, 1000);
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.USERNAME, "BrumbyUpdateTest");
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.CREATED_ON, new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.UPDATED_ON, new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.USER_TYPE, "Poster");
            userRecordResult.get(0).setValue(USER.PASSWORD, BCrypt.hashpw("12341234", BCrypt.gensalt()));
            result[0] = new MockResult(1, userRecordResult);
        }
        LOG.info("[execute] :: MockResult.rows=" + result[0].rows);
        LOG.info("[execute] :: MockResult.data=" + result[0].data);
        LOG.info("[execute] :: result=" + result.toString());
        return result;
    }

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        DataSourceFactory mockDataSource = mock(DataSourceFactory.class);
        ManagedDataSource ds = mock(ManagedDataSource.class);
        when(mockDataSource.build(any(), any())).thenReturn(ds);
        Environment environment = mock(Environment.class);
        try {
            when(ds.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            LOG.warning("[setupTest] :: sqle=" + sqle.getMessage());
        }
        userDAO = new UserDAO(mockDataSource.build(environment.metrics(), "ds"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdatePassword() {
        boolean out = userDAO.updatePassword(1000, "12341234");
        assertThat(out).isEqualTo(true);
    }
}
```

My understanding from reading the [jOOQ JavaDocs](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockResult.html) is that this should end up using the MyMockDataProvider and respond when an UPDATE query is executed with the result I created.  I believe that I am creating a new MockResult that has a row count of 1 and the User object in it that is specified.  When I look at the logging statements I put in there, that is what is happening.

```
    Jul 23, 2015 9:23:04 AM com.mycompany.dao.UserDAOTest$MyMockDataProvider execute
    INFO: [execute] :: MockResult.rows=1
    Jul 23, 2015 9:23:04 AM com.mycompany.dao.UserDAOTest$MyMockDataProvider execute
    INFO: [execute] :: MockResult.data={Expected Data Based on MyMockProvider}
```

But when I execute the unit test, UserDAO object is seeing the response from jOOQ as a record count of 0.

```
    Jul 23, 2015 9:23:04 AM com.mycompany.dao.UserDAO updatePassword
    WARNING: [updatePassword] :: count=0
```

The code that I am trying to test is the following:

```
public class UserDAO {
    public boolean updatePassword ( Integer id, String newPassword ) {
        try ( Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ) {
            DSLContext updatePassword = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
            int count = updatePassword.update(USER)
                    .set(USER.PASSWORD, BCrypt.hashpw(newPassword, BCrypt.gensalt()))
                    .where(USER.ID.eq(id))
                    .execute();
            LOG.warning("[updatePassword] :: count=" + count);
            if ( count != 1 ) return false;
            return true;
        } catch ( SQLException sqle ) {
            LOG.warning("[updatePassword] :: sqle=" + sqle.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I incorrectly using the MockResult object?  Maybe I am misunderstanding, but I believe the update returns me the record count impacted, which based on the MockResult I am returning that should be 1.  But the UserDAO object is returning 0 instead, and thus my test is failing.

Thanks in advance for any help, or a direction in which I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I am doing this right since I am answering my own question, but I think I am.  I spent the last two days looking into this and stepping through the jOOQ code to see what the issue was.  It turns out that issue was in what I was providing data within the MockResult object in this line of the test:

```
result[0] = new MockResult(1, userRecordResult);
```

Since I was not fetching data after the update, I shouldn't have included it.  Basically, I can remove all of the lines of code of building the userRecordResult object, and instead just set up the MockResult object as follows:

```
result[0] = new MockResult(1, null);
```

I believe this says to me there is a result, and no data.  Since there is no data returned now, the [MockStatement.execute0()](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockStatement.java) function now returns false instead of true. And then when in the [AbtractQuery.execute()](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/AbstractQuery.java) function, the if block from lines 410 - 413 is triggered and the result count is set to the value.

```
        if (!stmt.execute()) {
            result = stmt.getUpdateCount();
            ctx.rows(result);
        }
```

Before, when I had the data within the MockResult object, the MockStatement.execute0() function was returning true, and thus the if-block above was never executed, and the `result` int was never changed from when it was created to be zero. But with null data, the line `result = stmt.getUpdateCount();` is triggered and my value is set.

Comment: Thx a lot for this good explanation. I was also struggeling for update and this solved my problem! :)